# how to use uiimageview to view image from an array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

i create an app that contain an array of photos.
i have an UIImageView object and i want to show image from the array to my imageview.
how can i do this?

my array declaration:

```
     photoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     PhotoItem *photo1 = [[PhotoItem alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"] name:@"roy rest"  photographer:@"roy"];
     PhotoItem *photo2 = [[PhotoItem alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"] name:@"roy's hand" photographer:@"roy"];
     PhotoItem *photo3 = [[PhotoItem alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"] name:@"sapir first" photographer:@"sapir"];
     PhotoItem *photo4 = [[PhotoItem alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"] name:@"sapir second" photographer:@"sapir"];
     [photoArray addObject:photo1];
     [photoArray addObject:photo2];
     [photoArray addObject:photo3];
     [photoArray addObject:photo4];
```

another question:
how do i write a code that will create an uiimageview as the number of the object in my array??

thanks!!

Comment: How do you want to show the image? In a single imageview or 4 imageviews?

Answer (score 0):

Please refere below, Let me know is it useful or not ?

```
for(PhotoItem *photoItem in photoArray){
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:photoItem.imageProperty];
     [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the   UIImageView object to the uiscrollView  and then add the uiscrollView object i.e. scroll to the view...

```
    int y = 10;
    for (UIImage *img in array) {
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y,200, 400)];
        [imgView setImage:img];
        [scroll addSubview:imgView];
        y = y + imgView.frame.size.height + 5;
    }
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, y)];
```